# How can i separate value from one integer in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create one HTML page. There is one text box to enter integer value. If I enter one integer value, e. g. 123 as input, then I need to get output as x=1, y=2, z=3, how can I separate the integer in php?

Comment: what happen if some one inters 400 numbers. 400 variables?

Comment: <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method= "post">
<font color ="blue"> DICES VALUE : </font> <br> <input class=  "x" type ="text" name= "number" required>
<input class ="cube" type ="submit" value= "Cube"><br>
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    
    $name = $_REQUEST['number'];
    $x= ;
 $y = ;
 $z= ;
    if (empty($name)) {
        echo "<span style='color:red'> *Number is empty, you should enter some value.</span>";
    } else {
 
   echo "Y:<input class = 'my' type ='text' name= 'yvalue' value = '$x+$y+$z'>";}}
?>

Answer (score 5):

You can use [str_split](http://php.net/str_split)

> array str_split ( string $string [, int $split_length = 1 ] )

```
print_r(str_split('123'));
```

You can then use that array to populate your variables, this works well for strings of varying length as a bonus.

However if the length will always be 3 you can also do

```
list ($x,$y,$z) = str_split('123');
```

**Note:** I'm almost always against the use of quotes around numeric values - and this code will work equally well without those - but i put them here just to put things into the context where the actual entity being split is a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can access directly your string variable as an array of each character. (called php string as array)

```
$myvar = "123";
echo $myvar[1]; //Display 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code :

```
<?php

$str = "Hello Friend";

$arr1 = str_split($str);
$arr2 = str_split($str, 3);

print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => H
    [1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => l
    [4] => o
    [5] =>
    [6] => F
    [7] => r
    [8] => i
    [9] => e
    [10] => n
    [11] => d
)

Array
(
    [0] => Hel
    [1] => lo
    [2] => Fri
    [3] => end
)
```

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Comment: Might want to add a reference to it

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_split()`,
Then use the array directly instead variables like $X,$Y,$Z.

Answer (score 1):

there is code you need :

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method= "post">
<font color ="blue"> DICES VALUE : </font>
<br />
<input class= "x" type ="text" name= "number" required> <input class ="cube" type ="submit" value= "Cube">
<br />
</form>

<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_REQUEST['number'];
    $name = '123';

    list($x, $y, $z) = str_split($name);
    if (empty($name)) {
        echo "<span style='color:red'> *Number is empty, you should enter some value.</span>";
    } else {
        echo "Y:<input class = 'my' type ='text' name= 'yvalue' value = '" . $x . $y . $z . "'>";
    }
}
?>
```

**[LINK](https://eval.in/598176)**